# How to open file from command line in an already opened Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, file, command-line

The command

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe C:\PATH\TO\file.txt
```

opens a new instance of MS VS. I want to open files in an already opened VS, where I have my project defined and opened.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the `/edit` switch

Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7(v=vs.100).aspx

> Opens the specified files in a running instance of this application. If there are no running instances, it will start a new instance with a simplified window layout.

Comment: Doesn't work in VS 2022 :-(