# How can I open a file in an already-running instance of Visual Studio 2022 using the command line?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022, git-config

Many SO questions (such as [Visual Studio: How to open file from Windows command line to specific line in running instance of VS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219380/visual-studio-how-to-open-file-from-windows-command-line-to-specific-line-in-ru) and [How to open file from command line in an already opened Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895464/how-to-open-file-from-command-line-in-an-already-opened-visual-studio)) have already been asked about this, but the solutions discussed within don't seem to work for VS 2022.

So how can we do this seemingly-trivial task in VS 2022? MTIA! :-)

**P.S.** I actually want to pass this command line to Git's `core.editor` config setting, so that when I run e.g. `git rebase -i <commit hash>` or `git commit --amend`, I am presented with a new text editor window in the already-running instance of VS from which I run said command (using the integrated terminal).